# "Help toward reaching a goal": Why use "toward"?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, word-in-context

I've read this from Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

> avail: help **toward** reaching a goal

The word "toward" confuses me. Why doesn't the author use "for" or "in"?

> avail: help **for** reaching a goal
>
> avail: help **in** reaching a goal

The underlying question is what's the difference between "toward," "for" and "in" in this context.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, prepositions don't translate easily between languages: you need to know how a particular preposition can be used for each verb in the target language. In English, some prepositions can have twenty or more different meanings. Yes, that does sound like a lot of work, but that's the way it is.

**toward** is perfect because it can mean **getting closer to a goal** ([Oxford dictionary, meaning 1.1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/towards)).

**for** is not appropriate: while some of the other meanings seem plausible, its meaning is **to the benefit of** when used with **help**. ([Oxford dictionary, meaning 3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for)).

> the hearing aid was a great help **for** my mother

**in** works nicely because, when used with a verbal noun (reaching is a verbal noun), it means **as an integral part of (an activity)** ([Oxford Dictionary, meaning 8](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)).

Comment: this is better than my "because it is" answer :)